# French spacing for semicolon in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

When writting mathematics in a french document, you should use the semicolon instead of the comma to separate the coordinate of a vector or a point (for example). The problem is that in math mode, even with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, the spacing around the semicolon is wrong (it lacks a space just before it) and you must add `~` or `\,`.

How to get the semicolon working correctly in math mode?

Comment: There seems to be a solution here (I don't know if it is really efficient since I didn't test it myself): http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/espacement-autour-des-points-virgules-en-mode-maths-t8379.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) by the way :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to make the semicolon into a binary operator, if you always use the semicolon in math in those contexts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\;=\numexpr\mathcode`\;-\string"4000\relax}

\begin{document}

Point-virgule; une formule $(a;b)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach, which could be a feature request to the maintainers of `babel-french`, is to modify how the semicolon works when found in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\makeatletter
\declare@shorthand{french}{;}{%
  \ifhmode
    \ifdim\lastskip>\z@
      \unskip\penalty\@M\FBthinspace
    \else
      \FDP@thinspace
    \fi
  \else
    \ifmmode
      \mskip\thinmuskip
    \fi
  \fi
  \string;}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Point-virgule; une formule $(a;b)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beaten me for a few seconds...

Comment: @karlkoeller The train is on schedule. ;-)

Comment: As always... (yours). :-)

Comment: The fist solution works well and it’s very short, however the space behind the semicolon in math mode is larger than in text mode (or at least it seems to.) Sadly, the second solutions didn’t work.

Comment: First solution breaks with Polyglossia and Babel when using LuaLaTeX, but works when using XeLaTeX engine. The error returned is `Invalid math code during > 0x8000 mathcode fallback`. Any idea to fix this?