# Spacing before and after punctuation in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Compiling this minimal code with pdflatex or lualatex give this result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\[ (2;3) \quad 2,3 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Is it possible to automatically add a space before semicolon and remove the space after comma in math mode ?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what `(2;3)` and `2,3` represent in this case. If say in `2,3` the `,` is the decimal marker, I would suggest using `siunitx` and format the number using `\num{2,3}` (with the appropriate setting to have `,` be the decimal marker.

Comment: Yes colon is decimal marker (french) and semicolon is coordinates separator. In the past, spacing around semicolon was good (same before and after).

Comment: @MB4E Colon is `:`, semicolon is `;` and comma is `,` Please, be more precise in your question.

Comment: For the semicolon see [French spacing for semicolon in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226457/82917)

Comment: @egreg Yes I was confusing colon and comma. (post edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this behaviour of comma and semicolon in any use-case, you may use following "hack": change mathcodes of comma and semicolon:

```
\mathcode`\;="303B
\mathcode`\,="013B
```

In mathcode, first digit represents class of math symbol. Default semicolon and comma have class 6 (punctuation) so space is placed after that and don't before.

Class 3 is relations (like symbols +, – etc.) so thin spaces are placed at both sides.
Class 0 is ordinary symbols so spaces aren't placed.

In this case, if you will need to use comma as punctuation (e.g. in list), you have to put thin space after comma manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\mathcode`\;="303B
\mathcode`\,="013B
\begin{document}
\[ (2;3) \quad 2,3 \quad \{x,\,y,\,1,\,2,\,3\} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With any language package used, you have to enclose mathcode declarations is `\AtBeginDocument` command and place it after loading package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \mathcode`\;="303B
    \mathcode`\,="013B
}
\begin{document}
\[ (2;3) \quad 2,3 \quad \{x,\,y,\,1,\,2,\,3\} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, polyglossia is breaking the semicolon hack.

Comment: @MB4E, try to enclose mathcode declarations in `\AtBeginDocument` command: see additional sample code in my answer.